# All apps except WhatsApp cannot work on WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, sony-xperia

I'm having some strange problem with my Sony Xperia SL. I use Virtual Router Manager on my Laptop to connect my mobile to internet over Wi-Fi. Since this morning, none of the apps are connecting to Internet (Play Store, Instagram, Subway Surfers, Browsers, etc.) except WhatsApp.

I've tried resetting Settings on my phone. Also reset the Wi-Fi modem on my Laptop, but still the same. Any solution?

Comment: What about other wireless networks? What about mobile networks? Is your device rooted?

Comment: No the device is not rooted. I just can't understand how only whatsapp is working and not other app. Not even opening websites in browser.

Comment: what about mobile networks?

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning cache, e.g. using the [All in One Toolbox](http://www.appbrain.com/app/all-in-one-toolbox-%2829-tools%29/imoblife.toolbox.full), then restart your phone.

Answer (score 1):

It's a DNS problem. Try using Google's DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). Some routers let you change DNS settings.

Comment: What made you think it is a DNS server problem? Please back your claim with credible sources.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a wrong configuration on Windows Firewall.

1. Open your Windows Firewall in the control panel
2. Check if the firewall is on for Work or Private networks
3. If it is, then turn it off for this firewall

Now you should be able to connect to the internet again.

Comment: If its a firewall issue then why Whatsapp is working?

Answer (score 0):

You may have an incorrect DNS configuration. Check "Obtain a DNS automatically" or use a public DNS.